# Get recently created schema in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql

I have more than 150 schemas in PostgreSQL, every time when I perform an action a new schema will be created with some random name with numbers. It is hard to find which is the new schema created.

I use `\dn` to list schemas in PostgreSQL, but it doesn't display schemas in created order. How do I list either recently created schema or schemas sorted by creation date?

Comment: Not possible. Postgres does not store the date and time when things are created.

Comment: Then how do I find which is the schema that I created recently, is there any workaround for this

Comment: Your approach to create schemas with "random" names seems to be very questionable to begin with. But why not extend your code to log the time when it ran a `CREATE SCHEMA` statement? e.g. into some metadata table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any schema has `oid` column - numeric unique identifier (that is increased only). So you can use `ORDER BY oid DESC`

```
SELECT * FROM pg_namespace ORDER BY oid DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

Pavel's answer is good and may get you everything you need, but if you want more flexibility, I would recommend using event triggers:

```
CREATE TABLE schema_creation_history 
  (schema regnamespace primary key, 
   created timestamp with time zone not null default now()
);

CREATE FUNCTION log_schema_create() RETURNS event_trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO schema_creation_history (schema) SELECT objid::regnamespace FROM pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands();
END;
$$
;

CREATE EVENT TRIGGER schema_create_trigger 
  ON ddl_command_end 
  WHEN TAG IN ('CREATE SCHEMA')
  EXECUTE FUNCTION log_schema_create();

# create schema test;
CREATE SCHEMA
# select * from schema_creation_history ;
 schema |           created
--------+------------------------------
 test   | 2019-09-11 12:32:21.16346+00
(1 row)
```

You could add another trigger for DROP SCHEMA to make sure the table is cleaned up.